# How to make Angular understand that view child is of a specific type, not a general ElementRef?

Tags: angular

I have an element in my HTML like this (inspiration from [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component)). While the user types, I'm showing successive filtrations in a list to pick from. Once the user clicks on that component, I want to update the value typed in the search box below and replace it with the full name available in the clicked item.

```
<input #userSelector (keyup)="onKeyUpUser($event)">
```

In order to communicate easily, I have set up a view child as shown below. Then, in the handler of the click, I set the value picked.

```
@ViewChild("userSelector") userSelector: ElementRef;
...
onClickUser(user: User) {
  this.userSelector.nativeElement.value = user.name;
  ...
}
```

This works as expected. Now, I wanted to be clever and realized that the view child is not only a general `ElementRef` but, in fact, `HTMLInputElement`, so I replaced the code like this.

```
@ViewChild("userSelector") userSelector: HTMLInputElement;
...
onClickUser(user: User) {
  this.userSelector.value = user.name;
  ...
}
```

To my surprise, it doesn't update the contents visible on the screen. In the console, I can see that the field `value` has appeared and has the value I assigned. But it won't show. It's the same element, so I'm confused why this happens.

What's the reason this occurs and (how) can I use the more specific type of the view child (hence allowing to avoid the detour through `nativeElement` to get to the value field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed correct to type the property decorated with `ElementRef`, but it is just not enough: just add the generic type to `ElementRef`.

```js
@ViewChild("userSelector") userSelector: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
...
onClickUser(user: User) {
  this.userSelector.nativeElement.value = user.name;
  ...
}
```

The `ViewChild` decorator give you access to a typed `ElementRef` (in this case of `HTMLInputElement` => `ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>`), not to an `HTMLInputElement` one!

If you want to observe a child component, you will directly get the component instance (so, no need to type the property to `ElementRef<MyChildComponent>>`). In that case you can just do the following:

```js
@ViewChild(MyComponent) myComponent?: MyComponent;
```